# Synthetizable delay in VHDL FSM state

Tags: vhdl, delay, xilinx, synthesis, vivado

i am currently in the midst of writing a VHDL description of the unit(s) controlling a Sitronix ST7066U and LCD Module 1602A-1 for Xilinx Virtex-7, using Vivado Suite as my environment.

the Message Processing Unit is modeled with a 2-states (next state and outputs/conditions) FSM, but I have a huge issue.

Since the display has its own "operating times", as in the datasheet, I need to realize synthetizable delays inside my FSM when it reaches the states where the display itself is doing its things, and we cannot proceed with more character sending.

Such part was originally written like this:

```
          when count_i => --waits for I_MAX cycles for the internal setup of the display




if (I = I_MAX_tb) then                                                                    
                       I <= 0;
                       TRIGGER <= '1';
                       op_flag <= '1';                       
                else
                       I <= I + 1;
                end if;

                if op_flag = '1' then
                   op_flag <= '0';     
                   next_state <= init_state;
                else                    
                next_state <= count_i;
                end if;
```

but, in simulation, the state machines stays in count_i state and doesn't realize that a new state assignment has happened.

I have tried the following construct

```
 if (state'event) then 
                    I<=I+1;
                    if (I = I_MAX_tb) then                                                                    
                        I <= 0;
                        TRIGGER <= '1';
                        op_flag <= '1';  
                    end if;
                end if;
```

but it doesn't come close to working.

I am pretty sure it is a simple implementation issue, but, still...

(might be something related to my **process' sensitivity list** also?)

Comment: This [Tutorial](https://web.ewu.edu/groups/technology/Claudio/ee360/Cad/lcd_ct-2.vhdl) shows an example of how to wait the various times. There's been a question in the past that appears to have been withdrawn from Stackoverflow. The display was used on a Spartan-3e Starter Kit and one of the DE2s. Your snippet isn't a [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's also an example [here](https://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4096079) (the HD44780u is compatible with the ST7066U).

Comment: ok, thanks.
I have now implemented a process that Waits for fixed amounts of clock cycles, based on the tutorial linked here, and it works perfectly.